# How can I dissolve turkey powder in water?

Tags: mixing

I dehydrated the turkey breast, ground it in a blender, then ground it in a coffee grinder.  When I add it to water and mix it, only a small part of it dissolves.  How can it increase its solubility in water?

Comment: It’s a solid, so it’s never going to truly dissolve.  I think there are some questions on here about cocoa powder or spices that elaborate on the issue

Comment: Oh, and if the issue is clumping, try mixing it with a little bit of water, making sure that it’s fully wet, then add the rest of your water

Comment: See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8274/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22648/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/68571/67

Comment: Perhaps say what is your ultimate goal here. Are you trying to make turkey flavour Bovril for example? Ground dehydrated turkey breast is something I have never needed. Though I suspect if you used a fattier part of the animal, you could emulsify the fat and suspend some of the non-fat particles in it.

Comment: This is weirdly off-putting. Thinking about "turkey water" is most unappetizing

Comment: I was trying to make a protein powder. My goal is to drink it easily. It makes me feel like I'm drinking a spoon of sand in a glass of water. I need to fix this.

Comment: Maybe be mix it with something other than water with some fat content in it, like milk, cream or yogurt, sort of like a smoothie

Answer (score 3):

Meat   will never  mostly dissolve in water, because it mostly isn’t water-soluble. (If it were, how would you make chunky soup?) What you’re looking for is a smooth suspension of the particles. If you had special equipment like a wet grinder, you could *maybe* produce a homogeneous enough slurry that could be dried and reconstituted (though it’s not what a wet grinder is really designed for). But I don’t think this is something a coffee grinder could do effectively.

Comment: If it were, turkeys would dissolve when it rained!